# How to Enable Scala plugin typsafe hocon support on IntelliJ Idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, typesafe, hocon

I recently updated Intellij Ultimate to 2019.2.2

Since the update .conf files are interpreted as smarty PHP configuration files and I dont have the usual Scala typsafe file support.

How do I Enable Scala plugin typsafe hocon support on IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

I ended up

1. Installing Hocon plugin
2. Associating Hocon file type with *.conf
3. Dissociating SmartyConfig file type with *.conf

To manage associations go to preferences > Editor > File Types

Answer (score 1):

HOCON support was moved to a [separate plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10481-hocon).

[Source](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/blob/c0fd2f685b18c5649c51049238099312852bec2b/README.md#scala-plugin-for-intellij-idea)